# Asymptote and ePiX: What is the advantage of one over the other?

Tags: graphics, asymptote

Links: [Asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net), popular vector graphics language.
[ePiX](http://mathcs.holycross.edu/~ahwang/epix/ePiX.html), is also similar software created by one of the top Stack Exchange members.

Both are based on C, which is nice for me because I hate the TikZ syntax. And looking at the gallery for both, they have really impressive diagrams. I have been using Asymptote for a month now, but after looking at some of @Andrew D. Hwang answer's beautifully drawn figures, I want try ePiX.

I am not asking which is better or worse. But, what is the advantage of one other the other? Where does he greatest strength and weakness of these packages lie.

Comment: I wonder why it's not in texlive?

Comment: For 3d images only: According to the introduction in its manual, ePix does not do hidden surface removal. Asymptote does (but only when producing rasterized output).